# Problems with AMD/ATI driver updates

Tags: windows-7, laptop, installation, video, drivers

I have a Windows 7 64 bit laptop. I own an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470, when I attempted to update from V12.6 to V12.10 it only installs the HDMI/DP Audio Driver V7.12.0.7708. I have cleared my system of everything ATI related and ran a full reinstall only to see the Audio Driver and Install Manager get installed. I have found a driver that runs a full installation but its from 2010 (V8). This old driver is usable but has a very hard time running newer video games. At this point any information on this subject would be helpful, if there is a fix to this problem please let me know.

EDIT: System Specs

1. ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470
2. Windows 7 64 bit
3. Intel Core i3 CPU M 350 @ 2.27GHz, 2266Mhz, 2 Cores, 4 Logical Processors.
4. HP AC power adapter series : PP012A-S HP Part No.: 608428-004
5. 4 GB of RAM
6. Laptop: HP Pavilion dv7-4077cl

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, but are you using the mobility version of the drivers? I had some experience with people trying to install the desktop version in a laptop. Just in case you can download the latest drivers from here: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

It appears that HP blocks my computer from recieving any updates from AMD's site. I managed to get V12.6 back and am happy to have my computer running normally. But I am still blocked from updating to newer versions.